# How to get group-id in facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My goal is to get the members of a facebook group. Looks like I can do it but I need to know the [**group-id**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/members)

How to get that? For example - what would be the `group-id` for this group and how to find it: https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonears/?

Comment: may i ask what you want to do with the group members?

Answer (score 0):

Authorize with the `user_managed_groups` permission, use `/me/groups` to get all groups you manage and you will have the IDs. The members of groups you don´t manage should be none of your business anyway.

If you don´t manage the group, you can use the Search API, this would be the API call: `/search?type=group&q=pythonears`

Be aware that you may also get other groups, if they have the search string in their name.

Those are the only options you have. Everything else would be scraping, which is not allowed on Facebook - that´s how platforms like lookup-id.com do it.

Comment: No that's not true. I am able to get members names of a group I am a member of (not admin). That's all I am looking for.

Comment: what´s not true? i did not say it´s not possible, but you should be aware that they may remove that possibility sooner or later - the user_groups permission was removed because groups you don´t manage are none of your business, so it´s likely that all access will be removed.

Comment: i have added some information about groups you don´t manage. it is possible in a legal way too.